# ScalaCheck valid/invalid test boundary

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I'm using *ScalaCheck* to do some property-based tests in *ScalaTest*. Say I want to test a function, `f(x: Double): Double` that is only defined for `x >= 0.0`, and which returns `NaN` for arguments outside of that domain. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```scala
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.scalatest.prop.GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks

def f(x: Double) = Math.sqrt(x) // The actual function isn't important.

class FTest
extends FunSpec
with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {
  describe("f(x)") {
    it("must accept every argument value and handle it correctly") {
      forAll { x: Double =>
        val r = f(x)
        if(x >= 0.0) assert(!r.isNaN && r === Math.sqrt(x)) // Too simplistic, I know. ;-)
        else assert(r.isNaN)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this is fairly elegant and works, but I'm concerned about boundary checking, because I doubt that - in the general case - ScalaCheck is going to be able to find the boundary and test that the function responds correctly with the values either side of that boundary (>= 0.0 in this case). Of course, I can separate the two conditions using `whenever` (*ScalaTest*'s replacement for *ScalaCheck*'s `==>` operator), but that's more effort and a lot of generated values are wasted:

```scala
class FTest2
extends FunSpec
with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {
  describe("f(x)") {
    it("must accept every valid argument value and handle it correctly") {
      forAll { x: Double =>
        whenever(x >= 0.0) {
          val r = f(x)
          assert(!r.isNaN && r === Math.sqrt(x))
        }
      }
    }
    it("must report the correct error value for invalid argument values") {
      forAll { x: Double =>
        whenever(x < 0.0) assert(f(x).isNaN)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(I know that I can also use a customer generator to limit the range so that `whenever` is not required, but I think that's beside the point. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about that.)

So, what I'm curious about is:

1. Is there a way to hint to ScalaCheck what the boundary value is, and ensure that it picks that value and the values either side of it?
2. Is there any alternative to this that is equally as elegant, but which does a better job of finding the boundary automatically?

Thanks for your assistance~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScalaCheck cannot automatically figure out which values your function treats as valid; you need to either encode this information in your properties (using something like `whenever`) or in your generators. Which approach to pick is context-specific.

Keeping properties "small" is preferable: focused, orthogonal properties are easier to read/write/maintain, and you can always compose them later to build more comprehensive properties. Therefore, I would keep the two properties (happy and unhappy cases) separate.

To avoid "wasting" generated values, I would use two separate generators (one for non-negative doubles and another for negative doubles); no need for `whenever` with that approach.

```
val genNonnegativeDouble: Gen[Double] = Gen.choose(0, Double.MaxValue)

val genNegativeDouble: Gen[Double] = Gen.negNum[Double]
```

Your properties would then look as follows:

```
final class FTest2
    extends FunSpec
    with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {

  describe("f") {
    it("must accept every valid argument value and handle it correctly") {
      forAll(genNonnegativeDouble) { x =>
          val r = f(x)
          assert(!r.isNaN && r === Math.sqrt(x))
      }
    }

    it("must report the correct error value for invalid argument values") {
      forAll(negativeDouble) { x =>
        assert(f(x).isNaN)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Incidentally,

- You should probably return something other than `Double.NaN` to indicate failure; an `Option[Double]` is a good candidate, here, as there is only one reason for failure.
- You should only check doubles for *approximate* equality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess you're not telling me anything I didn't already know. I had hoped there was some simple, concise way to simultaneously validate a function's response to both good and bad input, by informing _ScalaCheck_ where the input boundaries where. As for `Double.NaN`, that's what `Math.sqrt` returns when given arguments outside of its domain - I would never use that in my own code. :-) Since the purpose was to focus on the boundary conditions, I also wasn't too worried about using tolerances to verify `Double` values.

Comment: Incidentally, `oneOf` would pick 0.0 half the time. `posNum` and `negNum` only pick integer values. I think `choose` would be a better basis for a custom generator in this case.

Comment: @scalabling True. I will amend my answer accordingly.